# SQL split and merge string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this is my problem:

I got a string from a column like this:

```
**0756FJ89045GJD38**.pdf
```

Now i have to generate a path by this string:

```
/home/ars/07/56/FJ/89/04/5G/JD/38/0756FJ89045GJD38.pdf
```

I have to take two characters and build it up to one path level from left to right.

Maybe u can help me, thanks!

Comment: is the length of the string fixed?

Comment: I think you can find all the info you need at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Comment: no its variable, thanks

Comment: @jer What if the string cannot be broken into pairs of characters like if the string length is an odd number?

Comment: This is not possible, there is a validation which saves us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

```
DECLARE @p nvarchar(100) = '**0756FJ89045GJD38**.pdf',
        @n int = 3

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT STUFF(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@p,1,CHARINDEX('.',@p)-1),'*',''),1,0,'/') as p, 1 [level]
UNION ALL
SELECT STUFF(p,[level]+@n,0,'/'), [level]+@n
FROM CTE
WHERE LEN(STUFF(p,[level]+@n,0,'/')) >= [level]+@n
)

SELECT TOP 1 @p = '/home/ars'+p +'/'+REPLACE(@p,'*','')
FROM cte
ORDER BY [level] DESC

SELECT @p
```

Output:

```
/home/ars/07/56/FJ/89/04/5G/JD/38/0756FJ89045GJD38.pdf
```

**EDIT:**

If there is a table with PDF file names and all names are equal size, than you can do this way:

```
DECLARE @n int = 3

;WITH pdf AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    ('**0756FJ89045GJD38**.pdf'),
    ('**1729DA8CD189700A**.pdf'),
    ('**A6710936BCD47832**.pdf'),
    ('**00A764D617B93978**.pdf')
    ) as t(file_)
)
,cte AS (
SELECT file_, STUFF(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(file_,1,CHARINDEX('.',file_)-1),'*',''),1,0,'/') as p, 1 [level]
FROM pdf
UNION ALL
SELECT file_, STUFF(p,[level]+@n,0,'/'), [level]+@n
FROM CTE
WHERE LEN(STUFF(p,[level]+@n,0,'/')) >= [level]+@n
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES '/home/ars'+p +'/' + REPLACE(c.file_,'**','')
FROM cte c
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY file_ ORDER BY [level]) DESC
```

Output:

```
/home/ars/00/A7/64/D6/17/B9/39/78/00A764D617B93978.pdf
/home/ars/A6/71/09/36/BC/D4/78/32/A6710936BCD47832.pdf
/home/ars/17/29/DA/8C/D1/89/70/0A/1729DA8CD189700A.pdf
/home/ars/07/56/FJ/89/04/5G/JD/38/0756FJ89045GJD38.pdf
```

Comment: i will try it today and give a feedback ;)